# PWM signal with NMOS to adjust LED Driver

Tags: arduino, mosfet, pwm, led-driver

I have to design an LED driver for work. I am using the IS31LT3360 as the driver chip. On page 10 of its datasheet it states the chip can be driven with pwm. I came up with the following circuit. I would appriciate any feedback on wether I am doing this correctly. The mosfet is driven with a 0-3.3V PWM signal.

I am a little confused about this line on the datasheet:

"The PWM signal must have the driving ability to
drive internal 500kΩ pull-up resistor. "

What does that mean? I am not sure what driving a resistor means.

Datasheet IS31LT3360 :

http://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/31LT3360.pdf
[image]

Edit after Marcus's comment. The datasheet suggests using a MCUs output (AS LONG AS IT IS BELOW 5V AND ABOVE 1.2V, better?) as below to drive the chip.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I feel like I *should* write the following: couple of days ago, you were in the middle of design for your bachelor thesis, now you're deigning a LED driver for work. Especially if you're doing your bachelor thesis within a company (as opposed to at a university institute), make triple sure that you get enough time to finish your thesis. Talk to your boss about that. Calculate how many hours working on your bachelor's is supposed to take, and make 100% sure you get that time, and the company is on-board with that. I've seen industry bachelor theses fail due to the student working too much.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am working for an Institute. My bach. thesis is interconnected. This LED driver will go into the same system as my bach. thesis. Boss wants the machine to look prettier

Comment: You are working on your bachelor thesis? Please break your question down...tell us exactly which part of the sentence you don't understand. Do you know what "pull-up" is?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I know what a pull up is. I am not sure what driving a resistor means thoguh.

Comment: stupid question: what's the reason for Q9/R33/R34 at all? they seem to be wildly unnecessary.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the datasheet suggests a voltage level between 0-5V my signal is between 0-3.3V. R33 is to provide a discharge route for the gate capacitance. I see it in many other design driving mosfets.

Comment: @EmreMUTLU no, it doesn't. The next sentence says the high-going threshold is 1.2 V. So, your 3.3 V is totally sufficient. ("many other designs" doesn't matter – what matters is your design in your application, and my guess is that if your B.Sc. is about circuit design, then that's twice as true!) Instead, the datasheet actually suggests directly driving the ADJ pin from a microcontroller pin with naught but a series resistor (and a protection diode).

Comment: @MarcusMüller you are right

Comment: I hope the wording of your edit is not really the reason you chose the circuit you're displaying now in your question: The point is not that the datasheet has an example circuit with a component labeled "MCU", but that your MCU's voltage levels can directly work on the ADJ pin...

Comment: @MarcusMüller I get that Marcus... I dont think I am a moron. I am smart enough to draw basic conclusions.

Comment: @EmreMutlu I really don't think you're even remotely a moron! You're solving *big* problems! The pattern I saw is that albeit you seem to have a pretty solid theoretical background, you tend to say things like "a lot of examples do..." or "I saw that they filtered like...", without applying the full brute force of your intellect! Your own work is brilliant, don't let copying dilute that excellence :)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you haven't designed a level translator: -

[image]

It's a source follower and the voltage at the source will be approximately what is at the gate but about a volt lower in amplitude (MOSFET depending). It won't give a 5 volt PWM level translation. To do that you need the source connected to ground and a resistor from drain to 5 volts. This will produce what you need but, bear in mind it is an inverting stage so, 3.3 volts in produces 0 volts out and 0 volts in produces 5 volts out.

> *The PWM signal must have the driving ability to drive internal 500kΩ
> pull-up resistor. What does that mean?*

It means that when you have correctly re-wired your MOSFET as per the above, the loading resistance of the ADJ input is 500 kΩ but, given that it is a pull-up internal resistance, it's of little consequence given that the "to-be-added" drain pull up resistor (as per my earlier words) you would choose (about 10 kΩ) would swamp it.